# Where am I going wrong? android java.lang.NullpointerException logcat error

Tags: android, listview

**Where am I going wrong?**

I downloaded one project to display a list view from **`JSON`** using **`volley`** library. Running the project individually works perfectly fine. Then I created a navigation drawer, from where on click of it I can open the same list view. But when I try to do that my applications stops giving the following **`logcat`** error

```
10-27 03:06:18.072: E/MainActivity(1331): Error in creating fragment
10-27 03:06:18.072: I/Choreographer(1331): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-27 03:06:19.372: D/AndroidRuntime(1331): Shutting down VM
10-27 03:06:19.372: W/dalvikvm(1331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aafba8)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): Process: com.esggoa.iffi_app, PID: 1331
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.esggoa.iffi_app/com.esggoa.iffi_app.MovieFragment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.esggoa.iffi_app.adapter.CustomListAdapter.<init>(CustomListAdapter.java:26)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.esggoa.iffi_app.MovieFragment.onCreate(MovieFragment.java:54)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-27 03:06:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1331):     ... 11 more
```

the activity which gives the error is **`MovieActivity.java`**

```
public class MovieActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_movie);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        if(movieList != null) {
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);

        }
        else{
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            // Showing progress dialog before making http request
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();

        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my `CustomListAdapter.java`

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

This is the AppController.java file whos instance takes the null value but i am not getting how to resolve it

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {


     return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: com.esggoa.iffi_app.adapter.CustomListAdapter.<init>(CustomListAdapter.java:26)

Comment: The error is originating in your `CustomListAdapter.java`, line 26 - where is it?

Comment: can you please post you CustomListAdapter code ?

Comment: You are doing the Network Operation on the main UI thread. This is not acceptable by Android. First of all, improve your code to perform network operations on a separate thread or use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

NPE here:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

Your `AppController.getInstance()` returns `null` for a reason not seen here.

Comment: shall i post my appcontroller class to?

Answer (score 0):

Declare application name in your manifest as appcontroller as:

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController"
```

Comment: <application
        android:name=".AppController"